# WsException in WebSocketGateway not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket, nestjs

I'm playing with NestJs and stuck with one problem. I just can`t throw an exception in WebSocket gateway.

Everything is according to [this doc page](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/exception-filters).

I have tried to include

```
@UseFilters(new BaseWsExceptionFilter())
```

But... didn`t help.

```js
import {
    SubscribeMessage,
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer, WsException,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Client, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class EventsGateway {
    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    @SubscribeMessage('exception')
    exception(client: Client, data: number) {
        throw new WsException('Invalid credentials.');
    }
}
```

And I had smt like this...

```
/home/innistry/Projects/nest-likbez/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/hostReportError.js:4
[0]     setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
[0]                              ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: host.setType is not a function
[0]     at WsProxy.handleError (/home/innistry/Projects/nest-likbez/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-proxy.js:26:14)
[0]     at EventsGateway.<anonymous> (/home/innistry/Projects/nest-likbez/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-proxy.js:20:22)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: What's your nestjs version?

Comment: "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",

"@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",

"@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",

"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^6.7.1",

"@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.3",

"@nestjs/websockets": "^6.7.1",

Comment: I haven't tried out your code but could you update all your nest dependencies to the latest versions, e.g., with `npm update`?

Comment: Wow, that really helps! Thank you! "yarn upgrade" For those, who use yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because of a bug in an earlier version. Please update your dependencies to the latest version, e.g., with `npm update` or `yarn upgrade`.

Comment: npm update didn't work for me.
I had to manually change the packages to following versions and then run `npm update` after it:

`"@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0", "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0", "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0", "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^6.7.1", "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.3", "@nestjs/websockets": "^6.7.1"`

Comment: @Anon `npm update` only works within the specified update range. In your case the `^` updates to the latest minor release but not to the latest major release. See https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept